Equal or greater than inequality sign
I'm not good at English, so I used a translator so my words may sound strange.
If A is a natural number and B is 0, is A greater than or equal to B? At school, they said that it doesn't apply because A is never the same as B. However, since A is unconditionally greater than 0, isn't it true that A is greater than or equal to B?

Yes it is true.  $~A > B~$ implies that $~A \geq B.$

and the converse is not true?

$A \ge B$ means either $A > B$ or $A=B$.   That is true if one those are true.  As $A > 0$ is true, one of them is true.  So the statement $A>B$ or $A=B$ is true.  So $A\ge B$ is true.   I hope that answers what you are looking for.

"and the converse is not true?"  By converse do you mean: Does $A\ge B$ imply $A > B$?  No.  That is not true.  If $A=B$ then one of $A=B$ or $A>B$ is true, so $A\ge B$ is true.  But $A > B$ is not.  Consider "Let $N$ be a two digit number. Then $N\ge 10$".  That is true.  But $N > 10$ is not.  $10$ is a two digit number so $N$ could be equal to $10$.  If $N=10$ then $N\ge 10$ is true but $N > 10$ is not.

Also, a simple statement:  $5 \le 7$ is true.

First, it's worth noting that some people define natural numbers to include zero and some don't. In this case, we'll assume that they're excluded.
The expression $A \geq B$ is read to mean "$A$ is greater than or equal to $B$", and it's true when either $A$ is greater than $B$, or $A$ is equal to $B$. So if $A$ is always greater than $B$, then it is also true that $A$ is greater than or equal to $B$. In logic notation, we might write
$$A > B \implies A \geq B$$
i.e. $A > B$ implies that $A \geq B$, or we might say that $A > B$ is a sufficient condition for $A \geq B$. We might also say that $A > B$ is a stronger statement than $A \geq B$ because the implication only works in one direction (if you know that $A \geq B$ you don't know that $A > B$, because it might just be that $A = B$).
Basically, you're allowed to write $A \geq 0$ even if you know that in fact $A > 0$, but there might be reasons why that extra bit of information is important. In which case, you should write down the stronger statement.

"because the implication only works in one direction" $\quad$ To be quite pedantic: "because the implication isn't universal in the converse direction" (given that $(A\ge B\to A>B)$ is neither universally true nor universally false).
